# referencing a specific element when it's wrapped in another

Tags: jquery

So I am trying to dynamically generate some boxes on screen using divs and when you click on a specific one (`name=box1`) it executes certain code. When they were hard coded into my html the following code worked fine but now since I am wrapping them in a `p` it takes 'this' as a reference to the `p` not the `div`. I believe its line 11 that needs changing.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#swapboxes').click(function(){
        //build the box location array and boxes
        $('#boxeshere').html("");
        for(var i = 0;i < $.gameconfig.numofboxes;i++){
            $('<div class="boxes" style="background:#bf3215;height:100px;width:100px;left:'+200*i+'px;position:fixed;" name="box' + i + '" id="' + i + '"/>').appendTo('#boxeshere');
        }
  });
  //Execution for clicking on boxes
  $('.boxes').click(function(){
        if(this.attributes["name"].value == "box1"){
            $("#info").text("Congrats!!! You win!");
        }
        else{
            $("#info").text("I'm sorry, wrong box");
        }   
  });
});
```

Comment: there is not enough information in your question for anyone to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The click should stay on boxes.

The problem is that the .boxes are generated *after* page-load, when #swapboxes is clicked, but you've tried to bind a click event directly to something called boxes *at* page-load, when .boxes don't yet exist. That won't work.

With  the new .on() delegation method, you bind to an ancestor element (in this case, you've already got a jQuery object for #swapboxes) that exists at the time of the declaration (pageload), and delegate to the target element. Then, when #swapboxes feels a click (it will because the event bubbles up), it will look down for .boxes elements, and apply the action there. Like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#swapboxes').click(function(){
        //build the box location array and boxes
        $('#boxeshere').html("");
        for(var i = 0;i < $.gameconfig.numofboxes;i++){
            $('<div class="boxes" style="background:#bf3215;height:100px;width:100px;left:'+200*i+'px;position:fixed;" name="box' + i + '" id="' + i + '"/>').appendTo('#boxeshere');
        }
    }) 
    //Execution for clicking on boxes
    //delegate from #swapboxes, which exists on page-load, to .boxes:
    .on('click', '.boxes', function(){
        if($this.attr('name') == "box1"){
            $("#info").text("Congrats!!! You win!");
        }
        else{
            $("#info").text("I'm sorry, wrong box");
        }       
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the event is not being attached to the newly created element .. 
Because the newly created elements are still not existing on the page.

In cases like these you need to  delegate the event and it should work fine .. Try this

```
$('#boxeshere').on('click', '.boxes' ,function(){
        if($(this).prop("name") == "box1"){
            $("#info").text("Congrats!!! You win!");
        }
        else{
            $("#info").text("I'm sorry, wrong box");
        }   
  });
```

Here we are adding the event to the parent of the boxes, so even if a new element is added because of event bubbling the newly created element will be associated with the event.